# Behaviour of references in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am quite confused about the behaviour of the references in Java. I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {

    public ListNode removeNthFromEnd(ListNode head, int n) {

        // create aux Node before head
        ListNode aux = new ListNode(0);
        aux.next = head;

        ListNode first = aux;
        ListNode second = aux;
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { second = second.next; }

        while (second.next != null) {
            second = second.next;
            first = first.next;
        }

        if (first.next.next != null) {
            first.next = first.next.next;
        } else {
            first.next = null;
        }

        return aux.next; // YIELDS DIFFERENT RESULT THAN "return head;"
    }
}
```

Now the par that confuses me: In the first part of this method, I declare my variable `aux.next = head;` so the two variables `aux` and `head` now point to the same object. Then later in the code I create some pointers that do something do the nodes in the list, and return this same `aux.next` (hasn't been changed to anything since the beginning). And the result is different if returning `aux.next` than to returning `head`. So they don't point to the same object anymore, and the question is why?

Comment: You're not changing the value of `aux` anywhere, but you *are* changing the value of its `next` variable - because you've got `first.next = first.next.next`, where `first` has been initialized as `aux`.

Comment: It's hard to be more specific than that as you haven't provided a [mcve] or any more details than "yields different result". I suggest you run the code really carefully in the debugger - and ideally provide a [mcve] so that we can see the difference as simply as possible, in a concrete way. Then it'll be easy to pinpoint where things are changing.